# Masking out parts of an object for compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers, masking, id-mask

I am making a model of an Arc Reactor. In the model, there are some wires and a sphere with emission material, inside a glass material to create a glow effect.
Now I want to make these emitting objects glow and add flares in post-processing, so I was wondering if I could Isolate the emitting objects and mask out the objects in front of it so that I can mix the two images in post processing to make the whole thing glow.
Thanks.

My Final render:
[image: Final Render]

Emitting surfaces only:
[image: Emission Surfaces]

What I want (kind of):
[image: What I want]

Also, I think that the center ball-like emitting piece will block the foreground of the render which I don't want; So what would be a good way to composite it?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to mask for a glow? Isolating via masks will likely end up with a less than ideal output.

Comment: So what would recommend if I want to add a glow around the object?

Comment: This might be of some help to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMo67qBqc_0

Comment: Simply keep the scene referred ratios, and apply a generic glow. If you need an outer ring emission, model it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how can I model the outer ring emission? I have tried increasing the emission value but I loose the details. Actually I want the ring to glow but the glow should be blocked by the copper wire pieces.